# AMD error when I am installing build essential

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies, amdgpu

I am facing this error on a Dell Latitude E6540:

```
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation problem in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367272/installation-problem-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, my previous [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1367301/1460940) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367272/installation-problem-in-ubuntu-20-04) will fix this issue.

`amdgpu` and `amdgpu-dkms` are the problematic packages here because they are either not fully installed or corrupted.

Follow the below steps to fix this issue:

1. Purge the problematic packages:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -P amdgpu && sudo dpkg -P amdgpu-dkms
   ```

   More likely this will work! But sometimes it returns the same error.
2. In that case, you must manually delete it by running the following:

   ```
   sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/amdgpu* /tmp
   ```

   This will move all the components of the package you listed to the `/tmp` directory. You can later remove them if you want.
3. Then run these commands to update the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt -f install
   sudo apt clean
   sudo apt autoremove
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt upgrade -y
   ```

Feel free to ask me any questions in the comments. 
Good Luck!