# Installation problem in Ubuntu 20.04 (gnome, amdgpu - unistallation impossible)

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade, updates

I have the exact problem as: [Installation problem in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367272/installation-problem-in-ubuntu-20-04)
But nothing helps.
For example, when typing:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Ir replies:

```
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
```

It means: Errors are present during execution connected with: amdgpu....
It should be gnome that does it, but it goes with the original Ubuntu, so I did not chose this package.

Useless methods:

```
sudo dpkg -P amdgpu && sudo dpkg -P amdgpu-dkms
```

Output:

```
Done
```

But when repeating the above command same error is there.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/amdgpu* /tmp
```

Output:
E: Le dépôt http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu focal Release n'a pas de fichier Release.
[Translation: deposit http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu focal Release contains no release]
N: Les mises à jour depuis un tel dépôt ne peuvent s'effectuer de manière sécurisée, et sont donc désactivées par défaut.
N: Voir les pages de manuel d'apt-secure(8) pour la création des dépôts et les détails de configuration d'un utilisateur.

Further:

```
sudo apt update
```

Contains the same error (whish is above, in the question).
So, it seems Ubuntu is counter-intuitive on dealing with normal for OS problems.
Any tiny issue makes Ubuntu useless in installing new software, which is sad.
Can you, please, help with solving this problem?

PS:

```
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Result: OK
Then, say:

```
sudo apt update
```

The same error.

Comment: Uninstalling these AMD GPU drivers leads to Ubuntu system crash (system stops loading), so I can advise other users not to do so - Ubuntu has no core AMD GPU drivers that can replace what you have in your system :(

Answer (score -1):

AMD GPU driver removal leads to system crash.

There is only one way I have found to solve this problem.

I upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04 [in my case: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS; JAMMY].

Ubuntu 20 appears to be buggy with relation to the AMD GPU in GNOME.  I recommend not using this combination.

Upgrading to 22.04 resolved all my problems.  And installation of the software was very simple (Ubuntu 20, not so much).